# oracle sql how to distinct and remove all null values in the fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

hi how to distinct and remove all null values in the fields.
this is my original table. Im using sqldeveloper and oracle.

```
EMPNO      LASTNAME             FIRSTNAME            05-MAY-15                   06-MAY-15                   07-MAY-15                   08-MAY-15                   09-MAY-15                 
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
00000113   REYESUE              MARIE                +000000000 08:04:00.000000                                                                                                                  
00000113   REYESUE              MARIE                                            +000000000 08:12:00.000000                                                                                      
00000113   REYESUE              MARIE                                                                        +000000000 08:04:00.000000                                                          
00000113   REYESUE              MARIE                                                                                                    +000000000 08:06:00.000000                              
00000113   REYESUE              MARIE                                                                                                                                +000000000 08:25:00.000000  
00000114   SANTOSY              MICHAELA             +000000000 08:03:00.000000                                                                                                                  
00000114   SANTOSY              MICHAELA                                         +000000000 08:04:00.000000                                                                                      
00000114   SANTOSY              MICHAELA                                                                     +000000000 08:08:00.000000                                                          
00000114   SANTOSY              MICHAELA                                                                                                 +000000000 08:05:00.000000                              
00000114   SANTOSY              MICHAELA                                                                                                                             +000000000 08:09:00.000000
```

and this is what the output I wanted

```
EMPNO      LASTNAME             FIRSTNAME            05-MAY-15                   06-MAY-15                   07-MAY-15                   08-MAY-15                   09-MAY-15                 
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
00000113   REYESUE              MARIE                +000000000 08:04:00.000000  +000000000 08:12:00.000000  +000000000 08:04:00.000000  +000000000 08:06:00.000000 +000000000 08:25:00.000000
00000114   SANTOSY              MICHAELA             +000000000 08:03:00.000000  +000000000 08:04:00.000000  +000000000 08:08:00.000000  +000000000 08:05:00.000000 +000000000 08:09:00.000000
```

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: i didnt try anything yet. I still thinking how to start. I tried group by but its not the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate functions, `min`, for example:

```
select "EMPNO"
     , "LASTNAME"
     , "FIRSTNAME"
     , min("05-MAY-15") as "05-MAY-15"
     , min("06-MAY-15") as "06-MAY-15"
     , min("07-MAY-15") as "07-MAY-15"
     , min("08-MAY-15") as "08-MAY-15"
     , min("09-MAY-15") as "09-MAY-15"
from tbl
group by "EMPNO"
       , "LASTNAME"
       , "FIRSTNAME"
```